# Pygame - This game won't add to score

Tags: python, pygame

I'm making a rhythm game.
When a "beat" (arrow) hits a certain coordinate, it disappears.
If the corresponding key is being pressed, the game adds to the player's score.

But when I run my code, it doesn't add to the score.

Here's my code:

```
import pygame
import time
import itertools

pygame.init()
SCREENWIDTH = 1000
SCREENHEIGHT = 650
screen = pygame.display.set_mode([SCREENWIDTH, SCREENHEIGHT])
screen.fill((255, 123, 67))
pygame.draw.rect(screen, (0, 255, 188), (0, 50, 1000, 650), 0)
myfont = pygame.font.SysFont('Ink Free', 30)

background = screen.copy()
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
stageon = True

sprites = pygame.sprite.Group()
class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    sprite = pygame.image.load("Sprites/lee.png")

    def __init__(self, *groups):
        super().__init__(*groups)
        self.image = Player.sprite
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(topleft=(445, 550))
        self.pos = pygame.Vector2(self.rect.topleft)
        self.score = 0
    def update(self):
        key = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        dist = 3
        if key[pygame.K_DOWN]:
            self.rect.y += dist
        elif key[pygame.K_UP]:
            self.rect.y -= dist
        if key[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
            self.rect.x += dist
        elif key[pygame.K_LEFT]:
            self.rect.x -= dist

player = Player(sprites)

beatgroup = pygame.sprite.Group()
class Beat(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, ticks, image):
        super().__init__(beatgroup)
        self.image = image
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.pos = pygame.Vector2(730, 100)
        self.path = itertools.cycle(((730, 100), (850, 100),))
        self.next_point = pygame.Vector2(next(self.path))
        self.speed = 2
        self.ticks = 200

    def update(self):
        move = self.next_point - self.pos
        move_length = move.length()
        if move_length != 0:
            move.normalize_ip()
            move = move * self.speed
            self.pos += move
        key = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        if self.pos == (850, 100):
            self.kill()

        #here's the problem area   
        if self.pos == (850, 100) and  key[pygame.K_DOWN] and self.image == pygame.image.load("Sprites/down.png"):
            player.score += 10
        elif self.pos == (850, 100) and key[pygame.K_UP] and self.image == pygame.image.load("Sprites/up.png"):
            player.score += 10
        elif self.pos == (850, 100) and key[pygame.K_LEFT] and self.image == pygame.image.load("Sprites/left.png"):
            player.score += 10
        elif self.pos == (850, 100) and key[pygame.K_RIGHT] and self.image == pygame.image.load("Sprites/right.png"):
            player.score += 10

        if move.length() == 0 or move_length < self.speed:
            self.next_point = pygame.Vector2(next(self.path))

        self.rect.topleft = self.pos



class Beat_gen(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, order):
        super().__init__(beatgroup)
        self.image = pygame.image.load("Sprites/beat_cropped.png")
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(topleft=(730, 100))
        self.start_time = pygame.time.get_ticks()
        print(self.start_time)
        self.order = []
        self.picorder = []
        for i in order:
            self.order.append(i[0])
            self.picorder.append(i[1])
        self.currentbeat = 0
        self.LastBeat = 0
    def update(self):
        if self.currentbeat == len(self.order):
                stageon = False
        else:
            time_gone = pygame.time.get_ticks() - self.start_time
            if time_gone >= self.order[self.currentbeat] or self.currentbeat == 0:
                self.start_time = pygame.time.get_ticks()
                Beat(self.order[self.currentbeat], self.picorder[self.currentbeat])
                self.currentbeat += 1
                self.LastBeat = pygame.time.get_ticks()

class Hit_Line(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(beatgroup)
        self.image = pygame.image.load("Sprites/hit-line.png")
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(topleft=(873, 60))
        def update(self):
            self.image.draw()


beatgen = Beat_gen([(820, pygame.image.load("Sprites/left.png")), (410, pygame.image.load("Sprites/right.png")),(410, pygame.image.load("Sprites/left.png")),
                    (410, pygame.image.load("Sprites/right.png")),(410, pygame.image.load("Sprites/left.png")), (410, pygame.image.load("Sprites/right.png")),
                    (410, pygame.image.load("Sprites/left.png")), (410, pygame.image.load("Sprites/right.png")),(410, pygame.image.load("Sprites/left.png")),
                    (410, pygame.image.load("Sprites/right.png")),(410, pygame.image.load("Sprites/left.png")), (410, pygame.image.load("Sprites/right.png")),
                    (410, pygame.image.load("Sprites/left.png")), (410, pygame.image.load("Sprites/right.png")),(410, pygame.image.load("Sprites/left.png")),
                    (410, pygame.image.load("Sprites/right.png"))])

def main():
    while stageon:
        for events in pygame.event.get():
            if events.type == pygame.QUIT: 
                pygame.quit()
                return


        sprites.update()
        beatgroup.update()
        screen.blit(background, (0, 0))
        sprites.draw(screen)
        beatgroup.draw(screen)
        pygame.display.update()

        clock.tick(100)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Also, a note the way I tested to see if the score WAS going up was that in my original code, the score is displayed on screen. I also printed it to console.
And to prove it wasn't my bad rhythm game skills, I held down one key for a while (right now it just goes left right left right)

I've run through my code several times trying to find a problem with it, but I couldn't find it.

Any explanation would be appreciated.

Thanks :)

Comment: And you're sure the "beat" is exactly at the coordinates `850, 100` when you press the key?
Have you printed `self.pos` vs what is expected? Also, don't do `pygame.image.load()` **every** keypress. That's insane. Place the image in a local variable  and or use integers/strings to compare with, that will be extremely slow in the long run. What you also could do, is just add a `print('got here')` in the "problem area" if statements. Just to see if you even end up in those blocks, which I'm pretty sure you aren't. Most likely because `self.image != pygame.image.load()` instance issue.

Comment: The multiply-loaded copies of the same image are likely not comparing as equal.

Comment: That's the point i tried to get across, try doing `self.image == pygame.image.load("Sprites/right.png")` and only that. The instance of the two, will be different. You could probably do something like `self.image.path == pygame.image.load(...).path`, but that's ineffective. So try to compare by name/integer instead.

Comment: The part where the code checks if the key is being pressed is being skipped. That happens quite often to me. And I'm pretty sure it should detect a key press since I'm holding the key down. I tried to print something to the console after the part where it adds to the score but it didn't print.

Comment: I removed the part where it checks what the beat's image is. It works fine, but defeats the purpose of the images being arrows and makes the game too easy to cheat at.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's future me! How I solved it was that I added another attribute to the `Beat` class called `direction`, which is a string containing either "left", "right", "up", or "down".

To get this assigned, I went to the part where the `Beat_gen` gets initialised and in each tuple, I added another value, like so:
`(820, pygame.image.load("Sprites/left.png"), "left")`. Then I went up to the `Beat_gen` class and added a list called `dirorder` (direction order) and made a loop iterate through each tuple, get the third value and append it to the list, as done for the image and the timing.

Then added this to the `Beat` initialisation as an argument to assign it; `self.dirorder[self.currentbeat]`